# Series with reciprocal of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I'm stuck on this problem… I have to find the sum of $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{\binom{n}{k}}$$ with $n$ an even natural number. The book reports the answer and that's $\frac{2n+2}{n+2}$ but I sincerely don't know where to start. Some ideas?

The problem is took by *Advanced Calculus Explored*, by Hamza Alsamraee.

Comment: you can find an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251604/proving-that-sum-k-0n-frac-1kn-choose-k-1-1n-fracn1n

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I tried to found an answer before asking but i came up with nothing :(

Comment: Yes, this does happen, Cheers